# SFTP library for .NET?

Tags: .net, sftp

I am looking for a library I can use in a .NET 4.5x solution which, given a SFTP URL, username, and password, will allow me to connect to the remote sftp server and download files.  The library should...

1. be free
2. provide samples or documentations of how to use it

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I currently use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net). It has a .NET assembly that can be used to programmatically create and manage SFTP, SCP, FTP, and WebDAV connections.

Here's an example from their documentation:

```
using System;
using WinSCP;

class Example
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "example.com",
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "mypassword",
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
            };

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", false, transferOptions);

                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();

                // Print results
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  After I posted this, I asked a co-worker who suggested the same library.

Comment: For the *"given a SFTP URL..."*, use [`SessionOption.ParseUrl`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_parseurl) instead of assigning the `Protocol`, `HostName`, `UserName`, `Password` and `SshHostKeyFingerprint` individually.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Is that the recommended way to do it now? I pulled this example straight from the WinSCP documentation.