# I want to connect to the FileZilla sftp server with C# and automatically download the files I select to the folder on my computer, how can I do tha?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

```
string Host = "sftp...";
string Username = "login";
string Password = "password";

using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(Host, 88, Username, Password))
{
    try
    {
        sftp.Connect();
        if (sftp.IsConnected) //bağlantı başarılı ise buraya giriyor...
        {
            label1.Text = "connection successful.";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "connection unsuccessful!";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        label1.Text = "error!";
    }
}

//serverdan dosyaları indirmek için yazdığım kod
string remotePath = "sftp://login**/0001.7z";
string localPath = "\"C:\\Users\\Halis\\Desktop\\indirdiğim\"";
string host = "sftp...";
string username = "login name";
string password = "password";
//
using (WebClient sftpClient = new WebClient())
{
    sftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

    try
    {

        string sftpServer = "sftp...";
        string remoteFilePath = "sftp:/login**//0001.7z";
        string localFilePath = "\"C:\\Users\\Halis\\Desktop\\indirdiğim\"";

        sftpClient.DownloadFile($"{sftpServer}/{remoteFilePath}", localFilePath);   
       
        Console.WriteLine("Dosya indirildi.");
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hata: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I wanted to download it but I couldn't do it. Do I need a form application to connect or do I need to add a button to connect? I'm very confused.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `WebClient` for SFTP. There's actually no native SFTP support in .NET at all.

You have to use a third party library.

See:

- [SFTP library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36774687/850848)
- [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848)